# Deploying ASP.NET Core project via Azure DevOps (VSTS) to Azure WebApp missing files within site/wwwroot

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I want to deploy an **ASP.NET Core** project to an **Azure WebApp** via **Azure DevOps Build Pipeline**.

My project structure looks like:

```
MyProject
   -> src
      -> Project1
         -> Project1.csproj
         -> ...
      -> MainProject
         -> MainProject.csproj
         -> ...
  -> test
     -> MyProjectTests
        -> MyProjectTests.csproj
        -> ...
```

So the projects are inside a folder "*src*", which maybe leads to problems within the Build Pipeline.

**My build pipeline settings:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

So there is no error within the build pipeline, but the **dll's within site/wwwroot are not updated, like deploying manually**. I only can see the **folders containing the full source of the different projects** within *MyProject/src*...
So the structure on the web app looks like:

```
site/wwwroot
   -> Project1
      -> Project1.csproj
      -> ...
   -> MainProject
      -> MainProject.csproj
      -> ...
```

So I deleted all files within site/wwwroot and when I deploy via Azure DevOps I get following error on the WebApp: *You do not have permission to view this directory or page.*
When I change the setting "package or folder" to MyProject/src/MainProject I get following error on the WebApp: *HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure*

Is the package or folder settings wrong or something else?

And also, **no tests can be found to execute**..
Here is a part of the log:

```
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0038771Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0042959Z Test assemblies : **\release\*test*.dll,!**\obj\**
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0043286Z Test filter criteria : null
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0047373Z Search folder : D:\a\1\s
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0049408Z Run settings file : D:\a\1\s
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0051612Z Run in parallel : false
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0053271Z Run in isolation : false
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0075597Z Path to custom adapters : null
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0076007Z Other console options : null
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0078359Z Code coverage enabled : false
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0079452Z Diagnostics enabled : false
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0084375Z Rerun failed tests: false
2018-11-19T17:32:55.0087931Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2018-11-19T17:32:56.2022983Z ========================================================
2018-11-19T17:32:56.4234339Z ##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\release\*test*.dll,!**\obj\**.
```

Comment: That's the wrong source.  You at the very least need to be pointing to `MyProject/src/MainProject` for the source.  You might want to update the question with some more detail on the full project structure, the settings that you are using for the DevOps build pipeline, and concrete examples of the file issues that you are seeing when deployed,

Comment: Anyone else? :)